# Homotopy type of a complex affine variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine variety of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

> Does the analytic space associated with $X$ have the homotopy type of a $n$-dimensional CW complex?

Comment: see paper of Milnor , http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnorcw.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $X$ is smooth, and if you ask to have the same homotopy type of a CW complex of real dimension *at most* $n$, this is precisely the statement of the Andreotti-Frankel theorem.

It is true, more generally, for a Stein manifold of complex dimension $n$.

If $X$ is arbitrarily singular, the same theorem holds, provided $X$ is irreducible. This was shown by Karčjauskas for algebraic varieties and by Hamm for Stein spaces.

Comment: When $X$ is any algebraic variety (in particular, any affine variety ), the aforementioned CW-compex is also *finite*. This implies that the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ and the homology and cohomology groups $H_i(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$, $H^i(X, \, \mathbb{Z})$ are all finitely generated. This is not true anymore fror an arbitrary smooth Stein space, for which the CW-complex can be infinite. Take for instance $$X=\{x \in \mathbb{C}\, | \, \sin x \neq 0 \}.$$